# Spark SQL DataFrame - Exception handling

Tags: scala, exception, apache-spark-sql

In our application , most of our code is just apply `filter` , `group by` and `aggregate` operations on `DataFrame` and save the DF to Cassandra database.

Like the below code, we have several methods which do the same kind of operations[`filter, group by, join, agg`] on different number of fields and returns an DF and that will be saved to Cassandra tables.

**Sample code is:**

```
 val filteredDF = df.filter(col("hour") <= LocalDataTime.now().getHour())
.groupBy("country")
.agg(sum(col("volume")) as "pmtVolume")

saveToCassandra(df)

def saveToCassandra(df: DataFrame) {
    try {
        df.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
        .options(Map("Table" -> "tableName", "keyspace" -> keyspace)
        .mode("append").save()
    }
    catch {
        case e: Throwable => log.error(e)
    }
}
```

Since i am calling the action by saving the DF to Cassandra, i hope i need to handle the exception only on that line as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33262363/uncaught-exception-handling-in-spark) thread.

If i get any exception, i can see the exception in the Spark detailed log by default.

Do i have to really surround the filter, group by code with `Try` or `try , catch?`

I don't see any example on Spark SQL DataFrame API examples with exception handling.

How do i use the `Try` on `saveToCassandra` method? it returns `Unit`

Answer (score 1):

There is no point wrapping the lazy DAG in try catch.
You would need to wrap the lambda function in Try(). 
Unfortunately there AFAIK there is no way to do row level exception handling in DataFrames.

You can use RDD or DataSet as mentioned in answer to this post below 
[spache spark exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35404903/spache-spark-exception-handling)

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to surround the `filter`, `group by` code with `Try` or `try` , `catch`. Since, all of these operations are transformations, they don't get execute until an **action** is performed on them, like `saveToCassandra` in your case.

However, if an error occurs while **filtering**, **grouping** or **aggregating** the dataframe, the catch clause in `saveToCassandra` function will log it as action is being performed there.